# DBus proxy Javascript binding issues

Tags: linux, javascript

Gnome 3 (under GNU/Linux, BSD or other Un*x) now offers a *gnome shell* with nice presentation, but where the configuration and theming are to be done via a web browser (and a public URL, on a public server).

I know that having two questions for one is not welcome there, but the link between the questions is strong.

Here are my questions:

- Could this *feature* become a security issue?
- If yes, how could I manage access (even block) this?

For example allowing or disallowing JavaScript in the browser; I would be able to allow or not JavaScript access to dbus, maybe with some limitations, like on IP or a ssl-certs list...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can result in a security  issue.It is like any web interface accessible from the internet.If the authentication system is not proper, an attacker might bypass it.

On how to manage access.

Depending on the kind of infrastructure that you have in your network, you can setup a VPN and enable access to the interface through the VPN.( you will use a private IP address to do the configuration)

I am not sure about the ways to block the web configuration entirely.